# Good usage of async methods in helping class

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, asynchronous

So i have a `Helper` class for accessing database using EntityFramework. In the class, all i have is mostly async methods for retrieving data from DB. Methods looks like this:

```
public class Helper
{
     private static Context db = new Context();

     public async static Task<List<Something>> getSomethingAll()
     {
         var a = db.SomethingList.ToListAsync();
         return await a.ConfigureAwait(false);
     }

     .... //lots of other methods coming here
}
```

And then in my WPF window code-behind I call method like this:

```
List<Something> sthList= Helper.getSomethingAll().Result; //good concept?

//use of sthList...
```

I am aware this is not the best way for using async methods. So what should i do in my example, to make it as usefull as it should be? Or maybe this is good usage?

Comment: Calling `.Result` is **never** good, and basically means "I'm doing this wrong" (with some **very** specific exceptions)

Comment: @MarcGravell So using async/await again in my code-behind would be a better solution?

Comment: In other news: `private static Context db = new Context();` is also probably a terrible terrible idea *if* `Context` has internal state such as a connection or an ORM db-context

Comment: Why do you even use `async` ? You're waiting for the result either way so IMHO it's useless.

Comment: To be more explicit, what you've shown is "sync over async", which is very explicitly an anti-pattern.

Comment: Well thanks for all the suggestions. Lots of work left for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var sthList = await Helper.GetSomethingAllAsync();

//use of sthList...
```

which will put you back in the right thread-state for resuming work (for example, you'll be able to touch the UI without it exploding), and won't deadlock horribly (`.Result` can do that when used incorrectly).